# Dell PowerConnect reboot - View unsaved changes?

Tags: switch, dell, dell-powerconnect

We have two Dell PowerConnect 7024 on our site and, for scheduled electrical maintenance; we’ll have to switch them off for a couple of hours.  This will be our first time doing this and, in order to prevent any issues, I would like to see, via a console connection, if there are any unsaved changes which are currently applied to the switches which might be lost on a reboot.

What command can I use to see any unsaved changes and, if this is the case, how can I save these changes so that the switches will reboot without incident?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used these in stacking mode, but assuming it's the same, you could compare the output of

```
show running-config
```

and

```
show startup-config
```

If you're happy with the running config, then

```
copy running-config startup-config
```